# MediatR - Registering IPipelineBehaviors with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, mediatr

I am currently trying to set up MediatR with my ASP.Net project using a Unity IoC container as the dependency resolver. I would like to use the `RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>` for handling some consequences of certain events (for example, sending an email or outputting a notification in the Client app).

I have been using code from the MediatR Examples on GitHub to register the relevant handlers (https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.Unity/Program.cs). Is there a good way to register a `RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>` for any number of `IRequestHandlers` I might register? Let me know if any other info is necessary.

Comment: be careful, the sample does not work with notifications.